# PHP site using ./dir/ for include files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have inherited a site that is using ./ notation for the include directories, and working locally, all the links are broken.

What can I do to my OS X AMP setup to get the ./ notation working for the relative document paths?

Comment: `./` will work on any platform.  What do you mean by "all the links are broken"?  What does that have to do with PHP?

Comment: I mean root directory ./ includes are not being picked up. Instead I get: Warning: include(/inc/head.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/path/to/site/root/index.php on line 1

Comment: When I open a "missing" image in a new tab, instead of localhost/siteurl/images/image.jpg , I instead get localhost/images/image.jpg (file not found, of course). Why aren't the ./ path prefixes working for local files / site-root?

Comment: You are describing two separate issues.  One is the include path for your application.  The other is relative paths for images and what not over HTTP.  In any case, it isn't possible to help you without seeing the path of your script, and the actual include line.  My guess is that on your other server, there was a specific include path set.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. I'll look for an include path constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not using `./`but absolute adress. in php if you want to work with absolute path, you have to use `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` before the path to make your adresses absolute.

`./` is not the root directory it is the current directory.

for example instead of `include('/inc/head.php');` you can use :

```
include(__DIR__.'/inc/head.php'); 
//or
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/inc/head.php');//if you haven't got php 5.3
```

In this code I assume the directory "inc" to be at the site root.

Comment: Okay, but ./ in the index.php is not returning the proper links, from the include paths to the .css stylesheet. Even current directory should be able to find the ./inc/include.php file from the index page, correct?

Comment: logicaly, yes. but I always disliked this notation as it is strictly equivalent to `path/file` I think css must be gave with relative adress or full URL (http: //....)